# Nuget Packages dependencies issue

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, dependency-management

I'm having trouble of dependencies in a chain of NuGet projects (Visual Studio 2019 and NuGet 5.7.0.6726).
The first project, include Log4Net NuGet package from NuGet.org, I package it with "nuget.exe pack mx_logging.vbproj -IncludeReferencedProjects" and I have my own (MX_Logging.nupkg).
A second Project use MX_Logging and i got the installation of Log4Net too, no problem so far...
Now, if i pack the second project too with the same method used before, it only have MX_Logging and not log4net as dependencies, how my i fix this?

This is the package.config in the second project root:

```
<packages>
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MX_logging" version="1.2.7668.29513" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Thanks a lot to everyone ;-)

Comment: Hi Alessandro, any update about this issue?

Comment: any update about this issue, please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

**In my side**, when I installed the second nuget project into a new `net framework 4.5.2` project, it has the `log4net` nuget dependency.

[image]

`log` is the first nuget project and `log1` is the second nuget project.

So please try the following steps:

**1)** delete `bin` and `obj` folder of the second nuget project.

**2)** [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

**3)** rebuild your second nuget project and then

```
cd xxx\xxx\the second project folder(where exists the csproj file)

nuget spec

nuget pack xxx\xxx.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

**4)** make sure the second nuget package and the first nuget package are all under the [nuget package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

**Update**

I used [nuget.exe cli v5.6.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) to pack the nuget project and I also test with `v5.7.0`. All are right.

**Actually**, I am guessing if you just see the second nuget package UI which does not list `log4net` nuget dependency.

[image]

**Although** it does not list `log4net`, but the log4net nuget dependency is under `log` nuget package. When you install `log1` nuget package, it will install `log` nuget dependency with its `log4net` nuget dependency. And it just does not show the dependencies of the inter-generation package. But the `log4net` nuget package really exists. Just as my first pic shows.

**But if** you still want to the dependency shown on the UI, or your nuget package really has some problems, you could try this：

modify the second nuget project's nuspec file and add these:

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency id="log4net" version="2.0.8" />
 </dependencies>
```

The whole nuspec is like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>1og1</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>me</title>
    ..........
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>

   <dependencies>
   <dependency id="log4net" version="2.0.8" />
   </dependencies>

  </metadata>
</package>
```

**Then**, repack your second nuget project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but nothing changed :/

Comment: I wonder if the second nuget package's UI does show the log4net dependency. If so, that is normal behavior and that UI does not show the dependencies of the inter-generation package. So you do not have to worry about that. And if you still want the display, please check my updated answer:)